# How to control web page using parameters separate with slash in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I want to create some wicket web page where I will use slash delimeter. 
Main page will be:

```
http://some.url/team/
```

will display list of team (Here I just mount wicket web page to team)

but now I have no idea how to do it in wicket. Url:

```
http://some.url/team/id/330/
```

should show detail of team with id 330 and

```
http://some.url/team/id/330/edit/
```

should show edit form to edit information about this tournament

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your `WebApplication` class:

```java
mount(new MountedMapper("/team/id/${id}", TeamPage.class));
mount(new MountedMapper("/team/id/${id}/edit", TeamEdit.class));
```

Then in the WebPage class:

```java
public TeamPage(PageParameters params){
    String teamId = params.get("id").toString();
}
```